# How to loop over a dictionary in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, swift5

In Swift 4 I could the code below worked but in Swift 5 I get the following error: `Type 'Dictionary<String, String>.Values.Iterator' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`

```
guard let userIds = users.values.makeIterator() else { return }

for userId in userIds {
    // User setup
}
```

What is the right way in Swift 5 now?

Comment: Even in Swift 3 I'd prefer `for userId in users.values { `, please see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894304-values)

Comment: `users.values.forEach {print($0)}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let dictionary: [String: Int] = ["a": 1, "b": 2]

for (key, value) in dictionary {
    print(key, value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply

```
for (_, userId) in users {
    // User setup
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try iterator like this:

```
 let users = ["a":11, "b":12]
 var userIds = users.values.makeIterator()
 while let next = userIds.next() {
    print(next) // 11 \n 12
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
let x = [
"kitty": 7,
"bob": 2,
"orange": 44
]
x.forEach { t in
    print("key = \(t.key); value = \(t.value)")
}
```

This has apparently been available since Swift 3. [Link to standard library docs on `Dictionary` type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1689593-foreach).

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4, swift5 and above

```
let dict: [String: Any] = ["a": 1, "b": "hello", "c": 3]

        for (key, value) in dict {
            print(key, value)
        }
```